# Update unique record in returns multiple record

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, subquery

In order to avoid the read-modify-write cycle (https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/) I am using a support table (`increment`) that increments and returns a unique value for various unique keys; combined with a log table that logs entries with the unique incremented value a particular increment key:

```
WITH increment_result AS
(UPDATE increment SET value = value + 1 WHERE key = 'my_key' RETURNING value)

INSERT INTO log (text, increment) VALUES ('my_text', (SELECT value FROM increment_result))
```

In a parallel and heavy load environment the query fails from time to time:

> PostgresException: 21000: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I cannot see why this is happening as `increment.key` is existing and unique. However I suspect it is related to the concurrency?

Any ideas why this occurs, or a approach to guarantee the a unique increment value?

Comment: why not just use a sequence to do that. `insert into log(text, increment) values ('my_test', nextval('seq_increment'))`

Comment: There is probably something wrong, describe your use case please

Comment: @YunLuo For a few sequences yes, but for many (any dynamically generated sequences) I find sequences  a bit messy

Comment: I wonder if this occurs during vacuuming.